# undefined method `content type=' for nil:nilclass in send_data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, content-type

I'm writing Unit test rspec for my controller
Here is my code:

**report_base_controller.rb**

```
def send_data_to_report
  params[:user_role_code] = @auth_logic.current_role.code

  report_url = @report_logic.report_url(params)
  res = @request_logic.get(report_url)

  check_request_code(res.code.to_i, params)
  filename = params[:call_docurain_flag].to_i.zero? ? '' : "buildee_v2.#{Constants::REPORT_OUT_TYPE[params[:file_code].to_i]}"

  if params[:file_code].to_i == 2
    send_data(res.body, filename: filename, status: res.code, disposition: 'inline')
  else
    send_data(res.body, filename: filename, status: res.code)
  end 
end
```

**report_base_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe "send_data_to_report 【帳票】出面及支払内訳書（請負）" do
  let(:report_setting) { create(:report_setting, report_code: '22',
    unit_code: 1, report_name: '【帳票】出面及支払内訳書（請負）') }

  let(:dummy_auth_logic) { double('dummy_auth_logic') }

  before do
    controller.instance_variable_set(:@auth_logic, dummy_auth_logic)
    controller.instance_variable_set(:@request_logic, dummy_request_logic)
    allow(dummy_auth_logic).to receive_message_chain(:current_role, :code).and_return(Roles::USER_ROLES[:PRIME])
    allow(dummy_report_logic).to receive(:report_url).and_return('')
    allow(dummy_http_response).to receive(:code).and_return(200)
    allow(dummy_http_response).to receive(:body).and_return('abc')
    allow(dummy_request_logic).to receive(:get).and_return(dummy_http_response)
  end
  it "Case 1" do
    expect(controller.send(:send_data_to_report)).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

But when I run the test I received the message

```
Failure/Error: send_data(res.body, filename: filename, status: res.code)
NoMethodError:
 #   undefined method `content_type=' for nil:NilClass
 #   ./app/controllers/api/private/reports/report_base_controller.rb:35:in `send_data_to_report'
```

I cannot understand that `content_type` belongs to which object, so I can't resolve the problem. Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: Try specifying the content type explicitly in the send_data

send_data(res.body, filename: filename, status: res.code, type: 'image/jpeg')

Comment: @SukeerthiAdiga I must not edit the report_base_controller's code, because I'm writing test for this controller (crying)

Answer (score 0):

`content_type` is a method from `ActionController::Request`, and more info can be found here:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

I'm not entirely sure how you can fix the error, but the problem is you are trying to mock a very complex rails object, and you are missing certain base variables it requires (`content_type`,  in this case).

In my experience I generally do an integration test on controllers, specially because RSPEC will handle all the request logic for me. If you choose to keep the unit test route you will have to deeply understand how ActionController works, in order to mock the request variables.

Good luck!